# Installing package with pnpm broke Next.js (or corrupted pnpm install)

Tags: ubuntu, next.js, wsl-2, pnpm

I just installed a new package (Radix-UI) in a Next.js project I was working on with no issues and suddenly **all Next imports throw `cannot find module` errors** and I cannot launch the project.

*edit: Just noticed other imports such as `fs`, `path` or css modules don't work either and JSX elements say `JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists.`

---

I did the following:

1. **`pnpm install @radix-ui/react-popover@latest -E`**

This threw two errors while installing:

```
ERR_PNPM_META_FETCH_FAIL  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pnpm: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/pnpm failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

ERR_PNPM_META_FETCH_FAIL  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@radix-ui%2Freact-popover: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@radix-ui%2Freact-popover failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
```

I believe at this point the Next.js imports were already broken.

After noticing nothing had changed in package.json and remembering the pnpm equivalent of "npm install" is actually "npm add" I did the following:

2. **`pnpm add @radix-ui/react-popover@latest -E`**

This got me another error:

```
ERR_PNPM_META_FETCH_FAIL  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-config-prettier: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-config-prettier failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
```

Since no changes are reflected in the code (and therefore git reset HEAD --hard does nothing), I am assuming something got corrupted with pnpm, but I am very new to both Next and pnpm, so I am a bit clueless here. Any idea what might be the problem?

---

*If relevant, I am working in a **WSL2 Ubuntu instance**.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the issue is (looks like it's caused by using "pnpm install..." instead of "pnpm add..."), but using `pnpm install` without arguments seems to have fixed things for now. Radix was still not installed so I had to add it again (this time with "pnpm add..."). 

Also, for some reason, on top of the existing package-lock.json, a `pnpm-lock.yaml` file has been added that was not there when starting the project with `pnpm create next-app --typescript`.

Comment: Update: it happened again when trying to install contentlayer and next-contentlayer and it seems pnpm (or wsl2?) does not like me having my vpn on. Just doing `pnpm add contentlayer next-contentlayer` with the vpn off worked.